# TUI apps not displaying anything under WSL

Tags: ubuntu, display

I installed a new WSL (v1 unfortunately), ubuntu 20.04. I run it with wsl.exe .

Both nano,vim and tried also neovim display nothing when launched. Tried updating them.
I mean the screen is completely blank, and they don't function. I had to quit with `<c-z>`.
I tried strace and saw not much interesting.

It gets to this loop:

```
select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1638377604, tv_usec=995640}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1638377604, tv_usec=995773}, NULL) = 0
```

The terminal works as expected generally.
Important update: it works as intended under ssh(TUI apps as well).

Comment: try prefixing the command with "winpty" e.g., winpty vim

Comment: "winpty command not found"